# Looking for steel pipe glides that have ball bearings for smooth movement and that can hold a lot of weight

Tags: steel, storage

This may not be the right place to ask this, but I'm not sure where is really.

I'm looking to build something in my home that slides in and out on steel pipes, about 1.5-2" in diameter, and that can hold up to ~300lbs on two pipes (so weight would be distributed onto 4 guides). I'm looking for round guides that can house the pipe and that have ball bearings for smooth movement. I've looked online and there are solutions for 3D printers and CNC machines, but those are either incredibly expensive because the machines they're made for have very low tolerances and need to be made very precisely, and/or don't come in 1.5-2" diameter (they're usually much smaller).

I'm not looking for anything fancy, and doesn't need to hold the pipe very tightly, just something that will allow the pipe to glide one way and the other (I'll also install some stoppers and clips to hold it when it's pulled in or out but that's much easier to find).

Ideally it would have screw holes either perpendicular or parallel to the pipe, either is fine. Also, I do need to use a cylindrical pipe as that is a necessity for what I'm working on.

Here's a picture that hopefully better describes what I'm looking for. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: For sliding/gliding, you probably want nylon/maybe bronze bushings instead of ball bearings.  Ball bearings mostly for rotation/turning.

Comment: @crip659 That's a great suggestion. I didn't know that those would be better, I'll look into that and see what I can find. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Solid steel rods can hold more weight than pipe at a smaller size.  Think I would try farm supply(what I know) first, seen those types of holders there.  Weight holding will depend on length, but ~300# need about 3/4 to 1 inch if not too long(a few feet).

Comment: What you are describing is called a linear ball bearing. See example here: https://www.mcmaster.com/9338T41/

Comment: Auto parts stores would be a good location to check for steering and/or suspension bushings. I don't know of many that get quite that large - maybe you'd need to head to a truck stop as large truck diesel parts could be that large.

Answer (score 3):

This one would be two step install.

Get 4 caster with up to 660 Pounds capacity.

They come in different tube size.

This one is for 3/4" tube size

[image: caster]

Second step is to get L shaped mounting hardware to mount the casters on the wall.

Install them upside down and pull the pipe true, to prevent it from falling out

Answer (score 1):

Go to a gym and ask them who maintains their equipment.  Some of the weight machines use glides and rollers that can carry unbelievable weight. I'm sure parts are replaceable.  Also google gym equipment parts. Something should lead you to what you want.